# Irregular bootstrap slider step values

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-slider

I am using bootstrap slider http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/
I want to select in irregular step values like, 14, 90, 360 days.

[Example Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/jLOA080eW89Dm39MZ6Dk?p=preview)

```
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text"  data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" data-slider-ticks="[14, 90, 360]"
   data-slider-ticks-labels='["14 days", "90 days", "1 year"]'
   />
 var r = $('#ex1').slider()
            .on('slide', function(data){
               $("#ex6SliderVal").text(data.value)
            })
           ;
```

Any suggestions how to select only those defined values 14, 90, 360 etc.

Comment: You can try this slider instead: http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/. See example 13 where you can set the ticks. You can still stop the slider in between values, but this might be as good as you can get without modifying the plugin

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to allow user to select in between values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this solved by author seiyria

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var realValues = [14, 60, 120, 365];
  var labelValues = ['14d', '60d', '120d', '365d'];

  var r = $('#ex1').slider({
    max: 3,
    min: 0,
    step: 1,
    ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    formatter: function(val) {
      return labelValues[val];
    }
  })
  .on('change', function(data){
    console.log(data);
     $("#ex6SliderVal").text(data.value.newValue + ' ' + realValues[data.value.newValue])
  })
 ;
})

 <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text"
       />
      <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
```

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PRTWdm2XKXcTAtyzVnG1?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :)